# java.lang.IllegalStateException: [Assertion failed] - this state invariant must be true

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-batch

I'm using the same code from the http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-tasklet-example/ (no custom implementation yet), but I've used all the current latest dependencies and found following issue. As I'm newbie to Spring-Batch does not able to track this issue

Any quick help is much appreciated.

The error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [Assertion failed] - this state invariant must be true
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:399)
    at com.mkyong.tasklet.FileDeletingTasklet.execute(FileDeletingTasklet.java:27)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at com.mkyong.App.run(App.java:26)
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:14)

Apr 07, 2015 12:43:16 AM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher run
INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=readMultiFileJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
Exit Status : FAILED
Exit Status : [java.lang.IllegalStateException: [Assertion failed] - this state invariant must be true]
Done
```

The pom.xml for your reference:

```
<properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <mysql.driver.version>5.1.35</mysql.driver.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

On request, here is my xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- stored job-meta in memory --> 
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Two comments:
1.  Post your configuration if you'd like us to help debug it.
2.  Check out the Spring Batch Getting Started Guide on the Spring website: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/.  It has more recent information than the post you're referencing...

Comment: Ok, I've already given the code location, If you want I can add spring-servlet.xml file here. Please let me know

Comment: I meant your spring configuration file...the XML from your application context.

Comment: Assert.state(dir.isDirectory()); - are you sure you are passing a directory path to tasklet?

Comment: Luca Basso Ricci - Yes, I'm using the Assert.state(dir.isDirectory()); in "FileDeletingTasklet" class

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<property name="directory" value="file:csv/inputs/" />` to `<property name="directory" value="classpath:csv/inputs/" />` in your batch job xml file.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to explain how this will solve the problem.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.